# The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>' exists in both dlls

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, async-await, async-ctp

I get the following error while compiling the code.

The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' exists in both 'c:\Go\WP7CodeSamples\Pradna\packages\AsyncAwaitCTP.1.0\lib\sl4-wp71\AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll' and 'c:\Go\WP7CodeSamples\Pradna\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.3.0.2-beta2\lib\sl4-wp71\System.Threading.Tasks.WP71.dll'

not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: I removed wp71.dll reference. But now it gives two errors :

Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' is not defined or imported 
 Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly? 

those errors come at my calling method:                                                                                                                                          public  asyncSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>  UpdateAppTile()
        {
          await fetchempdetails();
          }

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old version of Async CTP. If you are still on Visual Studio 2010, download [Visual Studio Async CTP (Version 3)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983). If you are using Visual Studio 2012, get the targeting pack from NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async.