# The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>' exists at multiple locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, resharper

I have added a service reference. After adding this on the code build it is giving the following error:

> The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' and 'e:\ShoeBooks\Project\ShoeBooksSync\packages\JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK.8.2.1158\bin\System.Threading.dll'    E:\ShoeBooks\Project\ShoeBooksSync\ShoeBooksSync.Web\Service References\ShoeBooksService\Reference.cs   25  32  ShoeBooksSync.Web

I have also seen the "packages" folder in my project root directory. Is this affecting anything?

Comment: I have also added the resharper to my project. This may be causing this issue. Please help how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: I know that you can think that is a stupid thing but have you try simply reboot visual studio.Sometimes happen the same to me.It show me issue on built but when i reboot vs all work fine.However take a look where the issue happen(col-row) in your editor and see if there's something strange.

Comment: Both `.net 4.5` and `JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK.8.2.1158` Nuget package contain that type.

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing the threading.dll from the resharper package folder.

Comment: This is an issue with the ReSharper SDK - it's a .net 3.5 app that's using the .net 3.5 System.Threading, and that clashes with the .net 4 System.Threading.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you have the ReSharper SDK installed into an asp.net application? The ReSharper SDK is only if you're trying to build a ReSharper plugin.

Comment: You can check this out if it helps. Seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775015/the-type-system-threading-tasks-tasktresult-exists-in-both-dlls